# pandas: select value from column name given as a value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, select

I have following dfs:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [94, 170, 5],
                   'b': [31, 115, 8]}, index=[11, 12, 13])

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'idx': ["a", "b", "a"]}, index=[11, 12, 13])
```

**I need to select value from either column `"a"` or `"b"` of `df` based on value in `df1["idx"]`.**

I'd like it to be efficient, since my dataframes will be big.

Comment: This is not a correct duplicate. A simple lookup wouldn't work: reindexing must be performed on both axes, the source is not the same dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels) with `df1` as the reference to build `idx` and `df` as the source of data:

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df1['idx'])

out = (df.reindex(index=df1.index, columns=cols) # reindex on both axes
         .to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
      )
```

output: `array([ 94, 115,   5])`

As a new column in `df1`:

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df1['idx'])

df1['out'] = (df.reindex(index=df1.index, columns=cols)
                .to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
              )
```

Output:

```
   idx  out
11   a   94
12   b  115
13   a    5
```